# Magento 2 : make category name searchable

Tags: magento2

I would like to make the category name searchable, for example when a user is searching furniture I would like to display all products in furniture category. 
I looked into CatalogSearch but I was not able to make something working.

Thanks !

Comment: where you want to make category name searchable.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Learing_Code, I would like to make category name searchable in default Magento search module